# Print image from API in esc_pos package

Tags: flutter, dart

[image of the image when print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1pPN.jpg)
I want to print image in 80mm wifi/printer image come from API as string.

Some of the images print correctly and some do not.

My code:

```dart
  void testReceipt(NetworkPrinter printer, String img) async {
     Uint8List unit8List = base64Decode(img);
    Image? a = decodeImage(unit8List);
    print(decodeImage(unit8List));
     printer.image(a!, align: PosAlign.center);
     printer.cut();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Exactly I need to Print image come from API to Wifi Printer paperSize 80 mm

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it by change the width of the image

```
Uint8List unit8List = base64Decode(img);
image.Image? a = image.decodeImage(unit8List);
image.Image resized = image.copyResize(a!, width: 600, height: a.height);
printer.image(resized, align: PosAlign.center);
printer.cut();
```